# User-submitted internal links in a RoR site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're developing a Rails app where one class of users edit and create articles.  Sometimes these articles contain links which refer to other articles on the site.  What is the best way to do the following?

- Store the links in the database
- Render the links on the page

At the moment we have static links which are tied to the actual domain name - this obviously has to go.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Tying links to the _domain name_ does feel a bit heavy, but if you don't mind writing code to re-write links in all your articles every time you change your article layout, static doesn't feel so horrible to me. (I mean, you'll probably go to great lengths to _keep_ URLs stable over time to keep your Page Rank and users' stored bookmarks...)

Comment: Hmm okay.  It would be great if there was something I could write in the model which identifies links in the content that are internal, and records that they aren't just URLs but references to internal records.  Then, if the records change in some way it can update them.  Is this making any sense?

I think what you're saying is to write a rake task or something which checks all the links and changes them if their locations have moved.

Comment: Oh, it makes _perfect_ sense; you want something like the [`link_to` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), but one that understands _your_ data. Building a quick little parser to find all `[controller: foo ; action: bar; id: 12345]` in an article to output the correct links would be pretty keen. But it feels like some amount of work to solve the problem of "my URLs move often" -- when in fact, URLs should be very stationary and boring....

Comment: All great points.  I should probably stop trying to solve a problem which doesn't even exist.  The task is to change the URLs to 'be more dynamic', as part of a more general site-wide effort to replace things like static links in non-user-generated views.  I think that for now your initial suggestion will be good enough - remove the dependency on the domain name and leave it at that.  In the future, it might be interesting to use some kind of BBCode or Wikipedia-like syntax.  [article]'article name'[/article].

Comment: Definitely interesting; and perhaps even something that would be worth putting into upstream Rails code. It sounds neat. :)

Comment: ...so now I have 10x more enthusiasm for finding a neat solution to this.  I'll update this question if anything comes of it :).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a rails version below 3.1 you can use auto_link http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link

or if you are on rails version 3.1 or greater, there is a gem http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_autolink

You can pass the text as a parameter to auto_link.

Comment: This is partially useful, but only really solves the problem of converting plaintext URLs to actual links.  The main thing I'm looking for here is making rails aware that the URL is actually referring to a record it should know about.

Comment: not sure I understand, you want your app to discover all internal links?

Comment: Pretty much.  Just handle more gracefully the situation where there are internal site references within user-generated content.  See my comments above.  Thanks for the links by the way, I'll end up using something like this for sure.